# Where and how i can save the dateinput to a variable an manipulate on data

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using Shiny and R to create analytical reporting web app.I want to use the dateinput to extract or manipulate data in shiny app.I don't know where and how to save the dateinput data in a new variable and extract or manipulate data. Is it possible in shiny?

Comment: It's possible. I gave you a minimum working demo in my answer below - hope that is a good start and good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `ui` where you define the front-end, use `dateInput` and specify an id (our id is `myInput`):

```
dateInput("myInput", "Pick a Date:", value = "2018-04-29")
```

And in your `server`, you can use the value of `myInput` and map it to an output that can be shown on the front-end:

```
output$somedate <- renderText({ as.character(input$myInput) })
```

Remember to include the output in your front-end:

```
verbatimTextOutput("somedate")
```

See an example:

[image]

Comment: I want to use the date to extract data from the database for that i need to assign in some another variable and call a query using the variable or the date in date picker.